# Get number of results on Google search results in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-search

Is there any way to return the number of Google search results in Python3? I tried several way from SO but none of them are still working:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>> def get_results(name):
        re = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', params={'q':name})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, 'lxml')
        response = soup.find('div', {'id': 'resultStats'})
        return int(response.text.replace(',', '').split()[1])

>>> get_results('Leonardo DiCaprio')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in get_results
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Works fine for me, what version of bs4?

Comment: 4.4.1 - I don't know if Google search API limit the number of searching?

Comment: They almost certainly do but has it ever worked for you?

Comment: Yes, I did a search with over 100 words before. But is there another way to get rid of it?

Comment: What do you see when you print the html returned?

Comment: I see the short version of Ctrl + U, and my requests status_code is 503

Comment: Your code will not work with all locales. I suggest this instead of just replacing commas: `return int(''.join(filter('0123456789'.__contains__, response.text)))`

Comment: Wow, work like a charm. Thank you @ValentinLorentz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response` in your `get_results()` function is `None` because the request to Google returned an error page so the div you are looking for does not exist.  You should check for a successful response status before trying to parse the results.